# Can we register multiple custom request matchers while using VCR.py (cassette recording for python)?

Tags: python, vcr

If the answer is yes, then an example on how to use them will be great.

Am referring to the below part of documentation: http://vcrpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#register-your-own-request-matcher

Comment: SO is not a free coding service

Comment: @MadPhysicist: ok, removed it. I thought an example would be good to show case an answer to my original question "if registering multiple matchers while using VCR is possible?" The vcrpy documentation does not show any. What good an answer such as "yes" to this question would be to future users if the answer doesn't show how to do it?

Comment: Have you put any effort into figuring this out yourself? What can you show that's relevant?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I have a link to the docs in my question. I have a read up the docs and did not find an answer to it or atleast that's what I know based on my understanding of the docs. I have been trying something in my code in last couple of days and might actually have an answer to this question in a day or two. However, IMO, that doesn't change the fact that the answer to this question would make most sense if given with an example code snippet.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I found an answer to my question. Keeping everything else aside, I truly think that this is a useful question and answer for future SO users. Would you re-consider removing your downvote please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself and the answer is `Yes`, it is possible to have multiple custom matchers when using VCR.py It's actually similar to how the VCRPY docs show using a single custom matcher.

Below is a general structure on how it can be done:

```
def vcr_matcher_1(r1, r2):
    # logic for matching r1 and r2 requests

def vcr_matcher_2(r1, r2):
    # logic for matching r1 and r2 requests
```

In your recording code, you can use something like:

```
custom_vcr = vcr.VCR()
custom_vcr.register_matcher('vcr_matcher_1', vcr_matcher_1)
custom_vcr.register_matcher('vcr_matcher_2', vcr_matcher_2)
with custom_vcr.use_cassette('cassette_name.yml',
    match_on = ['method', 'scheme', 'host', 'port', 'vcr_matcher_1', 'vcr_matcher_2']):
```

The above example also shows you can mix your custom matchers with default provided matchers by VCR.py

Ref:
http://vcrpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#register-your-own-request-matcher